# Chrome memory limits

Tags: google-chrome

There are claims on the web (including on this site) about Chrome memory limitations, but the ones I've found turn out to be related to other issues. window.performance.memory reports a 793MB heap limit, which also seems to be B.S., unless I'm missing something, or unless a lot of stuff isn't stored in the heap.  Obviously there's a 32 bit address space limitation (except for Linux), so that's the ceiling for now until Chrome catches up with IE and FF and goes 64 bit.

Someone will say, as I've seen on this site and others, "why do you need so much memory" or "why don't you store stuff on the server" or "the browser's not the right place to do memory-intensive work." Peace. I've heard it, let's agree to disagree.

Anyway. I built a dumb test jig (link to fiddle below) to see how much memory can be allocated until Chrome becomes unstable. The answer appears to be "around 2G".  You can allocate more -- as much as 3G -- free it, allocate it, free it, allocate it, free it; but the browser ultimately gets sick.  It'll "aw snap" on you randomly, after the 3G has been freed, at some later time.

So either it's pissing on itself (a bug), or some routine is using the top bit of an address for a flag (like Visual Basic's string storage allocator does, for example), so walking into "negative" address space is destabilizing it. Does anyone know enough about Chrome internals to confirm the latter theory?  If so, that would put the high water mark at (2^31 - sum(other stuff including Chrome internals)), which would be as close to a final answer as possible.

Link to fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/marvmartian/evkDM/11/

```
// allocate lots of memory and fill it with stuff
function testalloc(megabytes) {
    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < megabytes; i++) {
        foo[i] = new Uint8Array(1000000);
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 1000000; ii++) {
            foo[i][ii] = (ii + i) % 256 ;
        }
    }
    function bletch(i, ii) {
        return foo[i][ii];
    }
    return bletch;
}
```